# Clean up string with many angle brackets

Tags: regex, tidy

I have the following bit of HTML

```
<div class="article">this is a div article content</div>
```

which is being "tagged" by an HTML-agnostic program on the words `div`, `class` and `article`, resulting in:

```
<<hl>div</hl> <hl>class</hl>="<hl>article</hl>">this is a <hl>div</hl> <hl>article</hl> content</<hl>div</hl>>
```

although what I really need is:

```
<div class="article">this is a <hl>div</hl> <hl>article</hl> content</div>
```

Since the output is utter garbage (even tools like `HTML Tidy` choke on it), I figured a regex replace would help strip out the extra `<hl>`s *inside* the HTML tag:

```
replace(/<([^>]*)<hl>([^<]*?)<\/hl>([^>]*?)>/g, '<$1$2$3>')
```

Now, this works but only replaces the **first** occurrence in the tag, that is, the `div`:

```
<div <hl>class</hl>="<hl>article</hl>">this is a <hl>div</hl> <hl>article</hl> content</div>
```

My question is: how do I replace **all** `<hl>`s inside the tag, so as to make sure the HTML remains valid?

Additional notes:

- I don't need the tag attributes at all (i.e. `class="article"` can disappear)
- I can change `<hl>` and `</hl>` for any other strings
- Yes, the output comes from Solr

**UPDATE**: I accepted jcollado's answer, but I needed this in Javascript. This is the equivalent code:

```
var stripIllegalTags = function(html) {

  var output = '',
    dropChar,
    parsingTag = false;

  for (var i=0; i < html.length; i++) {
    var character = html[i];

    if (character == '<') {
      if (parsingTag) {
        do {
          dropChar = html[i+1];
          i++;
        } while (dropChar != '>');
        continue;
      }
      parsingTag = true;
    } else if (character == '>') {
      parsingTag = false;
    }

    output += character;

  }

  return output;

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to isolate the body of the original <div>, run your tagging program on that, and then re-wrap the tagged text?

Comment: I can't really do that, as the text comes directly tagged from Solr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the piece of code below is helpful for you:

```
class HTMLCleaner(object):
    def parse(self, html):
        output = []
        parsing_tag = False

        html = iter(html)
        for char in html:
            if char == '<':
                if parsing_tag:
                    drop_char = html.next()
                    while drop_char != '>':
                        drop_char = html.next()
                    continue
                parsing_tag = True
            elif char == '>':
                parsing_tag = False

            output.append(char)

        return ''.join(output)

html = '<<hl>div</hl> <hl>class</hl>="<hl>article</hl>">this is a <hl>div</hl> <hl>article</hl> content</<hl>div</hl>>'

parser = HTMLCleaner()
print parser.parse(html)
```

The output for the given input is:

```
<div class="article">this is a <hl>div</hl> <hl>article</hl> content</div>
```

which I believe is what you're looking for.

The code basically drops all tags when another tag hasn't been parsed yet.

Comment: I love this solution because I was stuck in my head with a regex... sometimes it's just about thinking from a different angle.